# Select ul up to a certain depth

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

```css
ul, ul ul, ul ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Question:** is there selector, so I can use it to apply style for each n-deep `ul`?

For example:

```
ul > ul
```

Comment: What do you mean with "each n-deep ul"? Do you want to set a style for each ul at a specific level? What doesn't work with the solution you have? Can you give an example of the expected outcome and the actual outcome of your current solution?

Comment: when I use  `ul, ul ul, ul ul ul, ul ul ul ul, ...` it is for 4-deep solution. What if I have 20-deep ul? I dont want to define all of them

Comment: If you have more that 3 deep `ul` you probably need to rethink your approach in the first place...but other than that...no there isn't.

Comment: This would be simpler by defining a class and applying that class to the `ul` that you want

Comment: If you want to style differently each UL _n-level_, use CssClasses, otherwise, you need to type `ul > li > ul > li > ul ... {}` 
However, if you want to style all the levels exactly the same, just `ul {}` will work.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to apply the same styles for the n-deep `ul`. Why don't you just target `ul` alone? Like `#id ul` ? or if you need to target a ul in another `ul` then just do `#id ul ul`, that should cover your bases, assuming you are trying to apply the same style to the `ul` like the example you have given

Answer (score 6):

For starters, the selector `ul > ul` will not work as `ul` elements may not be direct children of other `ul` elements. You'd need to use `ul > li > ul` in this instance.

What you can do to target specific depth levels is root everything to the first `ul` element's parent. For example, if your top-level `ul` was a direct child of the `body` element, you can simply add `body >` into your selectors:

```css
body > ul,                           /* Level 1 */
body > ul > li > ul,                 /* Level 2 */
body > ul > li > ul > li > ul { }    /* Level 3 */
```

For what it's worth though, with the correct specificity the selector `ul` alone would be enough to apply the style to all your `ul` elements (if you're not wanting to just target specific depth levels).

A standalone selector to target a specific depth unfortunately does not exist. Perhaps you're approaching this in the wrong way though - why don't you add a `class` or `id` attribute to the specific `ul` you wish to style and use them as the selector instead?

Answer (score 3):

The properties you are applying are usually resets what we do on `ul` element, so writing something like

```
ul {
  //Reset properties
}
```

is more than enough to get it applied across the dom at any level.

Still for some reason if you want to target specific properties at specific levels you need to use `>` but make sure you cannot write <s>`ul > ul`</s> which is wrong as you cannot nest a `ul` element as a direct child to a `ul`.

So if you want to specifically target `ul` and not the general reset than use a wrapper element around first level of your `ul` and use a selector like

```
.wrapper ul {
  //targets all ul nested under .wrapper
}
```

Comment: yea I think people are over thinking this

Comment: I was going down this line too. Here's an example I was creating: http://jsfiddle.net/fdvfzoxz/